# The authorization in Postman

Tags: web-services, authentication, postman

I had built a web service with authorization, how can i set the authorization info in SOAP header by using the Postman for test?

```
POST /AuthForWebServices/WebService.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/SensitiveData"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Header>
  <AuthHeader xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
   <Username>string</Username>
   <Password>string</Password>
  </AuthHeader>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
  <SensitiveData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" />
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```